# Laravel storage upload Image and File

Tags: laravel, storage

I'm trying to save an image that is coming from my request in my storage, but something strange is happening: I have the following code

```
$ request-> file ('UploadIMG') -> store ('public'. '/'. 'clients');
```

when it is executed it saves the image in the following location

```
storage \ app \ public \ clients \ dUpBTL0V25h2Q1825IUmvvIZhcwVPixLaVDdItuG.jpg
```

I wanted to change this value and set a name, so I used the following code

```
Storage :: disk ('local') -> put ('clients'.'/'.$ fileName, $Image, 'public');
```

let's say my $ fileName has the value of 01.jpg when I run that storage it creates

```
storage \ app \ clients \ 01.jpg \ dUpBTL0V25h2Q1825IUmvvIZhcwVPixLaVDdItuG.jpg
```

it ends up creating a folder with the name of the image and places the image with the random name, how do I get a name for my image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`storeAs()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads) method to save uploded file and name it:

```
$request->file('UploadIMG')->storeAs('public/clients', $fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $file = $request->file('pic');
    $picName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $imagePath = '/public/clients';
    $file->move(public_path($imagePath), $picName);
```